# Devexprerss GridControl Datetime Column AutoFilter

Tags: silverlight, devexpress, gridcontrol

I want to customize autofilter row

I create template for autofilter row and set gridColumn AutofilterRowEdiTtemplate to my template

Its works for general column but for datetime column always show dateedit in Autorowfilter

i dont want dateedit to be shown on autofilter

what should i do?

tanx

Comment: Have you tried to ask this in the Devexpress forum?

Answer (score 0):

Check [ColumnBase.ColumnFilterMode Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridColumnBase_ColumnFilterModetopic), you can customize your filter mode for specific column. 
This is WPF grid Reference, but silverlight grid also have such properties. check [Filter Modes and Custom Filtering](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/CustomDocument5225)..

Code snippet for reference:

```
foreach (GridColumn column in grvAvailableCompnents.Columns)
{
    column.OptionsFilter.FilterPopupMode = FilterPopupMode.CheckedList;
    column.OptionsFilter.AutoFilterCondition = AutoFilterCondition.Contains;
}
```

Reference:
[GridControl.CustomRowFilter Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridControl_CustomRowFiltertopic)